# Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes, what can I do?

Tags: php, html, json, jss

I can't send info to php, it gets blocked.

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I used different and just 1 out of 3 pc makes the code work.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#loginAjax').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'prueba.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { myusuario: "hola" },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#result').html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#result").html("no vas a aprobar");}
        });
    });

    $('#redRegistrar').click(function() {
        location.href = 'registro.html';
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $recibido = $_POST['myusuario'];
    echo json_encode( $recibido );
}
?>
```

I expect it to say `hola`.

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/app_bloqui/prueba.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: I fixed the code formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are trying to access the `prueba.php` from a `file://` URI.
This is likely because you opened a HTML file directly in your browser, and cross origin requests are not supported for files.

Instead, you should place your HTML file with your javascript inside your web server, and then visit the URL.

For example, guessing paths from your error, you need to make move your HTML file to `C:/xampp/htdocs/app_bloqui/test.html` and then visit `127.0.0.1/app_bloqui/test.html`. This will mean that you will be on the same origin and the request will work.